# I have two radio button but the the form only can get one radio value even we choose different radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I want to get the value from radio button that we have choose then multiple with the number in grossSalary. The result will be display on a textbox called epf. There are an error happening, the form only get 0.09 value even we choose 11% radio button.

Here is my javascript

```
<script> 
function get(percent)
{
var percent = document.getElementById('percent').value;
var grossSalary= document.getElementById('grossSalary').value;
var epf = parseFloat(percent)*parseFloat(grossSalary);
epf = epf.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('epf').value = epf;
}
</script>
```

Here is my form coding:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Gross Salary</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grossSalary" name="gross_salary">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>EPF</label>
<input type="radio" id="percent" name="percent" value="0.09" onclick="get(this.value)">9%
<input type="radio" id="percent" name="percent" value="0.11" onclick="get(this.value)">11%
<input type="text" id ="epf" class="form-control" name="epf" >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id. Get the radio elements via name, iterate over them and when the element is selected, get its value.

Comment: Why do you pass this.value as argument of the function but then immediately overwrite it inside the function?

Comment: Did try the solution I post ?

Comment: @JazZ can i place js script and html in single php file?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it's better to keep them in separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the name instead of the id (because id has to be unique). Also, with jQuery, you could use the `change` event.

i.e. :

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Gross Salary</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="grossSalary" name="gross_salary">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>EPF</label>
    <input type="radio" name="percent" value="0.09">9%
    <input type="radio" name="percent" value="0.11">11%
    <input type="text" id ="epf" class="form-control" name="epf" >
</div>
```

JS :

```
$("input[name=percent]").change(function() {
    var percent = $(this).val();
    var grossSalary= $("#grossSalary").val();
    var epf = parseFloat(percent)*parseFloat(grossSalary);
    $("#epf").val(epf.toFixed(2));
});
```

Here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rzpjjmnz/5/) on JSFiddle.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** Don't forget to include jQuery source in your html file :

One file template :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Gross Salary</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="grossSalary" name="gross_salary">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>EPF</label>
    <input type="radio" name="percent" value="0.09">9%
    <input type="radio" name="percent" value="0.11">11%
    <input type="text" id ="epf" class="form-control" name="epf" >
</div>

<script>
$("input[name=percent]").change(function() {
    var percent = $(this).val();
    var grossSalary= $("#grossSalary").val();
    var epf = parseFloat(percent)*parseFloat(grossSalary);
    $("#epf").val(epf.toFixed(2));
});
</script>
```

Comment: i did place js and html code in a single page, there are no result is display. May you tell me where there problem? i only add <script> js code</script>

Comment: See my edited answer. It includes a one page example.

Comment: @XinTingCindy the first line who calls the jquery source it required.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JS or Jquery than always remember one key point that:

```
id: used for single selection
class: used for multiple selection
```

In your case you are using same id for different tags, in that case it returns the first matching html value.

So to get rid of this, you have to use class and iterate over them and get the values.

Comment: oh i see. Thanks you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: i am still working on it. I did change the id to ClassName but there are no result. any solution?